# Swift Xcode 7 error with app delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I'm trying to make app to convert my model paints to other model paints. Right now I'm working on having list in core data with my paints but ik keep getting a error. the error is

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the piece of code

```
let Delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
let managedContext = Delegate!.managedObjectContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

let Color1 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
```

I do not know what the problem is the only thing that i do know is that it is on the first line. The problem is with unwrapping Delegate. And so that means creating delegate is were it is going wrong.
**Does anyone know the problem?**
Thanks for looking at my question even if you didn't answer.

Comment: It is unlikely to be the first line. It is much more likely to be the second or last lines where you force unwrap a conditional. Set a breakpoint on the first line and single step to see where the problem is.

Comment: I did this and it came to be the second line but the error was with unwrapping a optional so that means it is the first line

Comment: No, the second line force unwraps the `managedObjectContext` from your delegate. My guess is that this is nil. Really though,my our first line should also be as! not as? Because if you can't get the app delegate that is a fatal error

Comment: I did what you said and now it gets interesting because on my iPhone i get the same error and while if i use iPhone 5S simulator i get the error on this line: `let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("PaintConverter Pro", withExtension: "momd")!` I really don't get the errors anymore.

Comment: That says it can't find the core data model called "PaintConverter Pro" which is why your managed object context is coming back nil. Make sure that this is the name of your core data model and you have added it to your target

Comment: Thx i will try that you might have a point because i did ad coredata later in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments of the question it worked after trial and error and eventually i also needed to delete the app but now i works.